# Neural network for generating interesting sets

Tags: data-mining, gan, frequent-itemsets

I'm facing the following problem:
There are $n$ items $U=\{i_1,...,1_n\}$. I have many examples $X$ where $X\subseteq P[U]$ (the power set of $U$). The goal is to create a system that given these examples, learns to generate "interesting subsets". By "interesting" I mean subsets that their elements have high correlations, but their support doesn't have to be very high. Also, there could be situations where different parts of a subset appear in the examples and I want to generate the corresponding subset, i.e.:

Example 1 - $\{A,B,C\}$

Example 2 - $\{B,C,D\}$

Example 3 - $\{A,C\}$

Example 4 - $\{A,D\}$

I would expect the system to generate the subset $\{A,B,C,D\}$ where $A,B,C,D\in U$.

I tought about training a $GAN$ that learns to generate binary vectors with indices correspnding to the items, i.e. $G(z)\in \{0,1\}^{|U|}$, but I'm not sure if there's much theoretical justice for that.

Other approaches I considered are Apriori algorithm but I ended up conviced that it is not appropriate for the specific task. I Also thought about training a bayesian network, with nodes as bernouli variables indicating the occurence of each item, but it falls because I have hundreds of items, and it makes the training impractical for $BN's$.

I'll be happy to hear more approachs on how to tackle this problem.